# Inserting a script on each page using InstantClick

Tags: javascript, ajax, pushstate, pjax

I'm using Reevoo on my e-commerce website and our products have reviews hosted on Reevoo. The code which they provide needs to be run on each page load.

I'm using InstantClick which uses `PJAX`, and have had to modify all my scripts to ensure that it works with this plugin, but the Reevoo script is causing problems. The script always runs when I refresh the page, but when navigating through the website, it will occasionally break and not run again until the page is refreshed.

This is the code which Reevoo gives us -

```
var trkref = 'CEX'; 
var myscript = document.createElement('script');
myscript.type = 'text/javascript'; 
myscript.setAttribute = 'data-no-instant', 'true';
myscript.src=('http://mark.reevoo.com/reevoomark/CEX.js?async=true'); 
var s = document.getElementById('reevoomark-loader'); 
s.parentNode.insertBefore(myscript, s);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are there any error messages in console?

Comment: How can it 'occasionally break' haha, there must be something?

Comment: Nah, it breaks as soon as I go onto a product page. If I just stick to regular pages, it's all fine. But there's no differences in that part of the code when you compare the regular pages to the product pages

Comment: Open up dev console in chrome. Then go from page to page and see if errors pop up on product pages. Could be a conflicting `js` file?

Comment: @BeatAlex Absolutely nothing. Can't be a conflicting js file because I only have one, and it loads the file initially and then doesn't load it again until the page is refreshed. The `PJAX` passes the file through on navigation, but for some reason it doesn't want to pass it through onto a product page.

Comment: Or download `fiddler2` and have a look at the errors?